# GIt hub actions

Tags: git, github

I am trying to set a github action to deploy the /docs folder into a hostinger server.
so far I tried the following:

1. created a subdomain (lsmicro.descsimp.online)
2. created a FTP Account (ftp.descsimp.online)
3. created .github/workflow/main.yml in the github repository root folder with the code:

```
name:  FTP Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name:  Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: FTP Deploy
        uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.3.4
        with:
          server: ftp.descsimp.online # Subdomain name?
          username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }} 
          password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
          local-dir: ./docs/
          remote-dir: ./public_html/lsmicro/
```

In theory this should copy the content of the docs folder into the subdomain folder /public_html/lsmicro/ on each push.
However, it does not push anything so far.  Is there a mistake in my code? or the placement of the yml file? or anything else?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path is wrong. It should be `.github/workflows` (notice the trailing "s").

You can see this official document: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/quickstart#creating-your-first-workflow